# Illegal start of expression java operators

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that evaluates a postfix expression.  My idea is to stack the operands and then pop out the necessary operands when an operator occurs.  I am trying to check if the input is an operand is an operator or operand, but the only "if" statement of this beginning code is returning "error: illegal start of expression" at the first instance of ||.  Am I missing escape characters or something else?  Thanks in advance.

```
public class Evaluate{
char input[] = new char[50];
Stack operands = new Stack();

    public string Evaulate(string input){
        for (int k = 0; input[k] != null; k++){
            char symb = input.charAt[k];
            if (symb != (+ || - || * || / || $){
                operands.push(symb);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't  this be `('+' || '-' || '*' || '/' || '$')`. But you cannot do this either. You have to compare each time like, `symb != '+' || symb != '-'...`

Comment: You need to treat those as characters, not literal operators. Put them all in single quotes. And you need a different comparison for each one, as @redflar3 says.

Comment: You have too many errors in your code, you may consider reading some introduction to Java.

Comment: Jimmy, the specific error message is *because* you had the naked characters. Changing the question to use real characters without showing the new error message makes the question invalid. Rolled back. If you're wanting to know why you get the (different) error when you use characters (`|| not defined for char, char`), that should be a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, conditions don't quite work that way:

```
if (symb != (+ || - || * || / || $) ...
```

What you should be doing is first comparing them with *characters* rather than "naked" Java tokens (or `$`).

You should also be doing *full* comparisons between each `||` or, since you're using negative logic here to detect non-operators, `&&`:

```
if ((symb != '+') && (symb != '-') && ...
```

---

There are a few other problems in your code which I haven't mentioned but that should fix your immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
symb != (+ || - || * || / || $
```

is not valid in Java. Even after closing the parentheses and quoting the symbols, like this:

```
symb != ('+' || '-' || '*' || '/' || '$')
```

it is *still* not valid. You may *want* it to mean something that it does not, based on the way we can use "or" in English (i.e., "symbol is not a plus or a minus or a star or a slash or a dollar sign"). But Java just doesn't do things that way.

Fortunately there is a better way to determine whether a character (in this case `symb`) is *one of a certain set of characters*:

```
if ("+-*/$".indexOf(symb) >= 0) {
```

This computes the position of `symb` within the string `"+-*/$"` which, if `symb` is one of the desired characters, will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. If it is not, the expression returns -1. So the `>=0` check serves as the membership check you are looking for.